# Outputting a symbol tied to an array (C++)

Tags: arrays, char

Essentially, I need this to display an asterisk for every car sold, however regardless of what is input in the first for loop, it only spits out the symbol once, what am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

const int NUM_EMPLOYEES = 3;

int main()
{
    int carsSold[NUM_EMPLOYEES];
    int i;
    int totalSales = 0;
    char symbol = '*';

    cout << "Welcome to the sales report program!\n";
    cout << "\nThis program will produce a monthly sales report for the amount of cars sold.\n";

    for (i = 0; i < NUM_EMPLOYEES; i++)
    {
        cout << "Enter the cars sold by employee " << i + 1 << ": ";
        cin >> carsSold[i];

        totalSales += carsSold[i];
    }

    cout << "\nMonthly Sales Sheet";
    cout << "\n(each * = 1 car)\n";

    for (i = 0; i < carsSold[i]; i++)
    {
        cout << "\nEmployee " << i + 1 << ": " << symbol << endl;
    }

    cout << "\nTotal cars sold for the month: " << totalSales;



    return 0;
}
```

here is the output:

Welcome to the sales report program!

This program will produce a monthly sales report for the amount of cars sold.

Enter the cars sold by employee 1: 3

Enter the cars sold by employee 2: 2

Enter the cars sold by employee 3: 4

Monthly Sales Sheet
(each * = 1 car)

Employee 1: *

Employee 2: *

Employee 3: *

Total cars sold for the month: 9

Comment: Your example is not self-contained.  Missing the includes, using, and definition of NUM_EMPLOYEES.  Also, it's really helpful if you can minimize the example.  In case hard-code carsSold values so the program comes with the input.  Tell us what output you are getting and what you expect.

Comment: It seems you are trying to generate a histogram per employee with the 2nd loop.  You need one loop to iterate over employees and either generate a string of count '*' or a 2nd loop for that

Comment: Please double check the output.  Don't you want 3, 2, and 4 '*' respectively?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the hint I gave you above:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

#define NUM_EMPLOYEES 3

...

cout << "\nMonthly Sales Sheet";
cout << "\n(each * = 1 car)\n";
for (i = 0; i < NUM_EMPLOYEES; i++)
{
    auto bar = new string(carsSold[i], symbol);
    cout << "\nEmployee " << i + 1 << ": " << *bar << endl;
}
cout << "\nTotal cars sold for the month: " << totalSales << "\n";

...
```

This result in this output:

```
This program will produce a monthly sales report for the amount of cars sold.
Enter the cars sold by employee 1: 3
Enter the cars sold by employee 2: 2
Enter the cars sold by employee 3: 4

Monthly Sales Sheet
(each * = 1 car)

Employee 1: ***

Employee 2: **

Employee 3: ****
```

Comment: Thanks a ton for the help Allan! I realized using str.assign(carsSold[i], '*') worked great.